# Bind a ipv6 port to a ipv6 client socket. But the port binded is different than the one specified

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I am trying to bind a ipv6 port to a ipv6 socket. But the port binded is different than the one I specified.

```
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int unconnected_sock_ =
        socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM | SOCK_NONBLOCK | SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0);
      struct   sockaddr_in6 addr = {0};
      addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
      addr.sin6_port = atoi(argv[1]);
      addr.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
      if (bind(unconnected_sock_,
                       (struct sockaddr*)(&addr),
                       sizeof(addr)) != 0) {
                           fprintf(stderr, " error : %s\n", strerror(errno));
        }
        
        
        
        struct sockaddr_in6 sin;
        socklen_t len = sizeof(sin);
        getsockname(unconnected_sock_, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, &len);
       fprintf(stderr, "port number %d\n", ntohs(sin.sin6_port)); 
   }
```

```
output:

ubun - main: ~/socket.exe 54682
port number 39637
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please note that 54682 is 0xd59a, while 39637 is 0x9ad5. This is the same value, but written in different byte orders.

From `man ipv6`:

```
sin6_port is the protocol port (see sin_port in ip(7));
```

From `man 7 ip`:

```
sin_port contains the port in network byte order.
```

In the line that prints the port that is bind to the socket, you convert the network byte order to the local one:

```
fprintf(stderr, "port number %d\n", ntohs(sin.sin6_port));
```

In the line, that sets the requested port number, you are not converting the byte order from native to the network one:

```
addr.sin6_port = atoi(argv[1]);
```

To get expected behavior you should amend it to:

```
addr.sin6_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));
```

Comment: Thank you very much.